Software to generate a pretty simple entity-relationship diagram
It's a security app including:

RESIDENCE database
visitor database
security database
cleaning staff database
alerts database
complaint database
bill database

RESIDENCE TABLE
ResidenceID (Primary Key) 
OwnerName 
Address 
PhoneNumber

Visitor
VisitorID (Primary Key) 
Name 
IDNumber 
ContactNumber 
VisitDate 
CheckInTime 
CheckOutTime 
ResidenceID (FOREIGN KEY) 

Security
SecurityID (Primary Key) 
photo 
Name 
Shift 
ContactNumber

CleaningStaff
StaffID (Primary Key) 
photo 
Name 
Shift 
ContactNumber



Relationships


Visitor to Residence: Each Visitor is associated with one Residence, but each Residence can have multiple Visitors. Relationship: Visits Cardinality: One-to-Many (One Residence has many Visitors, but each Visitor visits only one Residence).
Security to Residence: Each Security might be assigned to multiple Residences, and each Residence might have multiple Security assigned.
Relationship: AssignedTo Cardinality: Many-to-Many (A Residence has
many Security , and each Security is assigned to multiple
Residences).
Cleaning Staff: Each Cleaning Staff member might clean multiple
Residences, and each Residence might have multiple Cleaning Staff
assigned for cleaning. Relationship: Cleans Cardinality: Many-to-Many (A Residence has many Cleaning Staff, and each Cleaning Staff member cleans multiple Residences).


ER Diagram Description:

Visitor connects  to Residence with a one-to-many relationship (each Residence can have
many Visitors). Security connects to Residence with a many-to-many
relationship CleaningStaff connects to Residence with a many-to-many
relationship

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

7 databases? Maybe 7 tables, right?

What are you trying to archive here? Where is the problem? Do you need a tool to see graphically those relationships?

Can you please format that monolithic block of test?  Seems to me like https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ might help

Did you have a look at e.g. plantuml (see e.g. plantuml.com)
